# pkg-config. Missing library's metadata

Tags: compiling, libraries, pkg-config

I'm building ffmpeg enabling over 40 libraries. Often a library is installed but metadata .pc file is missing.
Usually this could be solved by installing library-dev package but is there a way to just specify path to library somehow?

Comment: It is hard to determine what is wrong, but you could try to get build-dependencies of ffmpeg with `sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg` and then retry.

Comment: @N0rbert my question is more general. What are possible (and what is the professional)  solution for such kind of problem. It fills like one could manually find library required and supply its address on configure stage. Whole point of pkg-config is to find libraries automatically, but it fails.

Comment: Just add the path of pkg-config to the params `./configure --pkgconfigdir=/path/to/pkg/dir`

Answer (score 1):

On normally configured system the `pkg-config` does search for the needed `*.pc` files in the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`. You can find such files using [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=.pc) (really there are more than 19 such packages).

If you want to (or need to) override (or control) it, then define (re-define) the corresponding environmental variable to something like

```
export PKGCONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

and then run your compilation procedure.

In correctly configured system such `*.pc`-files should be installed and found automatically after installation of build dependencies for the package.
In your case it is done by `sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg`. This command will install many `*-dev` packages with `*.pc` files for them.